# RxJS: groupBy emits no values when used with timer

Tags: typescript, rxjs

New to `RxJS` (`^6.5.5`), I have an issue with the `groupBy` operator. Below is a stripped down example.

I have a function `retrieveFiles()` which returns an array of strings.

```
function async retrieveFiles(): Promise<string[]> {
  return ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'directory1', 'directory2'];
}
```

In reality this fetches an array of data from a remote source.

Let's say I want to group the filename by the first 4 characters.

Using `RxJS` I can do this as follows.

```
of(retrieveFiles()).pipe(
  concatMap(v => v),
  mergeMap(value => value),
  groupBy(
    (name: string) => name.substr(0, 4),
    (name: string) => name,
  ),
  mergeMap(group$ => group$.pipe(toArray())),
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

This will emit two values to the subscriber.

```
[ 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt' ]
[ 'directory1', 'directory2' ]
```

Now let's introduce `timer` and change the code slightly. We're basically polling now.

```
timer(0, 1000)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() => this.retrieveFiles()),
    mergeMap(value => value),
    groupBy(
      (name: string) => name.substr(0, 4),
      (name: string) => name,
    ),
    mergeMap(group$ => group$.pipe(toArray())), 
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

This no longer emits any values. What's the difference between these two?

Comment: there are bugs in this code `concatMap(v => v),` is invalid if `of(retrieveFiles())` is type `Observable<string[]>` is it supposed to be `Observable<Promise<string[]>>`? the `mergeMap(value => value),` section though is invalid in both cases.

Comment: Why would `retrieveFiles` need to return an Observable? Isn't `of` supposed to create that Observable for me?

Comment: `of` creates the observable yes, which is why the type of `of(retrieveFiles())` would be `Observable<Promise<string[]>>`

Comment: I'm mistaken, I forgot rxjs lets you play way more fast and loose with arrays and promises in newer versions

Comment: version 6.5.5 in this particular instance, I'll mention that in the question.Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to gather all emissions into groups when you poll or are you trying to generate entirely new groups when you poll?

Comment: The latter case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your second case, the difference is that `timer` never completes while `of` does, and `toArray` only emits when it's source completes, but the source isn't completing because the grouped observable from `groupBy` is expecting future emissions as `timer` is it's source, so it will never complete it's grouped observables.

If you want new groups generated for each poll, a minor restructuring is in order to make `retrieveFiles` its source

```
timer(0, 1000)
  .pipe(
    // recommend use switchMap so a hanging request doesn't clog your stream
    switchMap(() => from(retrieveFiles()).pipe( // need from to make it pipeable
      mergeMap(value => value),
      groupBy(
        (name: string) => name.substr(0, 4),
        (name: string) => name,
      ),
      mergeMap(group$ => group$.pipe(toArray())), 
    )),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

there is a valid discussion to be had here though, on if this is worth it. you can achieve the goal with a simple `map` operator with a synchronous array grouping function inside it rather than all the back and forth stream conversion.  If you're just exploring the library, that's cool, but in practice, I would not recommend doing this. `groupBy` use cases are uncommon but should be reserved for dealing with actual streams of values you want to group into separate observable streams

Comment: Started experimenting with RxJS because it was easy to setup the polling and emit a new value whenever a new file was found. Decided to see if I could group them as well. However I can just collect the files and handle the grouping outside of RxJS using `Array.reduce`. I don't have a use case for observing the separate observable streams.

Comment: yea, it's fun to poke around with but if this is your goal, an array reduce in a `map` operator seems like the way to go about it. would highly recommend moving to `switchMap` though if you're really using this for polling as `concatMap` will wait for a hanging request and can build backpressure, while `switchMap` will cancel and move on.

Comment: Didn't realise `toArray` only emitted when the source completes. Implemented the fix locally, works like a charm. Thanks for pointing out my mistake and the `swithMap` suggestion.